# Using ICollection's Remove method, with Entity Framework LINQ-to-Entities, crashes and closes connection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got the following two example entities ...

```
public class Document
{
  public int DocumentId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
  public int AuthorId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

Sounding this out, a `Document` can have multiple `Authors`.

I'm using Entity Framework's code-first approach. I'm using the `DbContext` fluent API for manually specifying schema binding details (as opposed to data annotations). Now, I'm entirely able to create a new `Author` using `ICollection`'s `Add` method, as follows ...

```
var document = dbset.ToList().First();
document.Authors.Add(new Author { ... });
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Where, `dbset` is an `IDbSet<Document>`, and `dbcontext` is the `DbContext` that all of these transactions are occurring within.

What seems to not work though is `ICollection`'s `Remove` method. The `Remove` call itself returns true, which I assume means that in-memory the removal worked. The thing the fails though is the call to the `DbContext`'s `SaveChanges` method. The following code will cause `SaveChanges` to throw an exception saying that the connection needs to be opened, which I've never encountered elsewhere in my normal usages of EF.

```
var document = dbset.ToList().First();
var author = document.Authors.First();
document.Authors.Remove(author);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

In the above code, `SaveChanges` throws an exception that literally states "The connection must be opened," even though right before it I query using the connection just fine. So, my analysis of this is that something about my entity classes or something causes something deep within EF to crash, thus closing the connection, thus me seeing that error instead of the real cause of the error.

Does anybody have an idea why I am unable to Remove this Author?

Answer (score 0):

In all of my projects that use EF Code First the DbSet isn't instantiated the way you're using it.  I can't replicate the "crash and disconnect" but I can get an error thrown.

I would suggest, instead:

```
var document = dbContext.dbSet
                .Include(ch => ch.Authors)
                .ToList()
                .FirstOrDefault();

if (document == null) return; 

var author = document.Authors.First();
dbContext.dbSet.Remove(author);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is the closest replica to your code that resolved the errors I found.

*Note:* there could be more info that you haven't yet provided, that happens sometimes ;)

Comment: I'm creating the `DbSet` in the same way that you are. With that in mind, the remainder of your code looks basically the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

just checking that you Multiple active result sets true...
eg

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBName ;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am using Postgres and this is not a feature for it.